# Separate csv files based on values

Tags: c#, csv

Please consider following csv separated with semi colon.

```
27356456;2;4001;3005;2100;20130125;
27356457;2;4001;3005;2100;20130125;
27356458;2;4001;3005;2100;20130125;
27356459;2;4002;3005;2100;20130125;
27356460;2;4002;3005;2100;20130125;
27356461;2;4006;3006;2104;20130125;
27356462;2;4006;3006;2104;20130125;
27356463;2;4006;3006;2104;20130125;
27356464;2;4006;3006;2104;20130125;
```

I want to store above rows in separate csv files based on the values at position 2, 3 and 4 (i.e. all rows with 4001, 3005, 2100 in one csv file and all 4002, 3005, 2100 in another file, and all rows with 4006, 3006, and 2104 in another file).

The values at those position can vary in actual data. I think it can be achieved with Linq or? Any hint will be appreciated.

```
private void ProcessTextFile(FileInfo csvFile)
{
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvFile.FullName, Encoding.UTF8))
  {
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
       string line = sr.ReadLine();
       string[] words = line.Split(";");
       ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a unique key for each file...something like...

```
string fileKey = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", words[2], words[3], words[4]);
```

Just append to a new file based upon which `fileKey` is discovered.

```
string filePath = @"C:\output\" + fileKey + ".csv";
File.AppendAllText(filePath, line);
```

Comment: Thanks. Good solution. But the problem is little bit complex as csv row also contains image filenames, which also need to be copied at the directory of csvs. It must be done at once to ensure that all rows and images are copied.

Comment: @mrd why not create a directory containing the fileKey? What do you mean with "at once"?

Comment: @derape: Actually, I already have a directory structure. For example, C:\PrepareImport\2100\3005\4001\ and C:\PrepareImport\2100\3005\4002\ and so on... The first three rows in the above csv file will be stored in C:\PrepareImport\2100\3005\4001\ and so one... "at once" mean, I want to separate rows in some dictionary or something then write the rows in separate csv files instead of appending.

Comment: Perhaps you should open a new question if you have new requirements. This certainly answers your OP.

Comment: @mrd Like SilverNinja stated, please open a new question for that. That is a different requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
var pathTemplate = @"C:\PrepareImport\{0}\{1}\{2}\filename.csv";
File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Split(';').Skip(2).Take(3))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => File.AppendAllLines(
        string.Format(pathTemplate, x.Key[0], x.Key[1], x.Key[2]), x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for all files one query:

```
var allCsv = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.csv")
    .Select(path => new
    {
        Path = path,
        Lines = File.ReadLines(path)
            .Select(l => new { Split = l.Split(';')})
            .Where(x => x.Split.Length >= 6)
            .Select(x => new { 
                Columns= x.Split
                    .Where((s, i) => i >= 2 && i <= 4) 
                    .ToList()
            }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();

// now you have all you need:
foreach (var csv in allCsv)
    foreach(var csvLine in csv.Lines)
        Console.WriteLine("File:{0} Columns:{1}", csv.Path, string.Join(",", csvLine.Columns));
```

(**edit**: i must admit that here's the point where Linq is not readable anymore):